# How to extract part of string in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How to extract part of string in bash? Suppose I have a string `product_name_v1.2`. This name is not fixed as it can be changed. However the one thing that is certain is that there will be a version umber in the string in a format like `v#.#`.

What I want to do is extract the `v1.2` and `1.2` from the string. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to extract digits and dots from the string:

```
input="product_name_v1.2_more_stuff_here"
echo "${input//[^0-9.]/}"
1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var=product_name_v1.2
#from the beginning strip (#) longest (##) glob ending in v (*v)
echo "${var##*v}
```

Bash has regexp matching too (with `[[` and `=~`) but [basic string manipulation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) should be enough for your use case.

(You can also check out [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for more information).

Answer (score 1):

In any POSIX shell, this is straightforward:

```
str=product_name_v1.2
version=${str##*_v}
echo $version
#=> 1.2
```

The construction `${`*name*`##`*pattern*`}` removes the longest prefix of the contents of the parameter `$`name that matches the glob *pattern*, leaving only what comes after it.

Comment: Not just bash; this is POSIX sh compliant. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesDuffy. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several standard tools you may use, e.g.:

- `expr product_name_v1.2 : 'product_name_\(.*\)'`
- `expr product_name_v1.2 : '.*_\(v.*\)'`
- `echo product_name_v1.2 | sed -ne's/^.*_\(v[0-9.]\+\)$/\1/p'`

The choice mainly depends on how complex the match needs to be. `expr` only supports a limited anchored regular expression match, which suffices in the examples above.